# How to disable call activity button for few Moments

Tags: java, android

i have a listview with phone call activity, but want to use this button only one or two times for 24 hours. after 24 hours it will be active automatically.

Comment: Why don't you use alarm for this? disable button and set an alarm(for 24 hours) when the user clicks the button. Then when you receive alarm, enable it

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to solve this question, try this:

```
 Button yourBtn = findViewById(R.id.yourBtn);
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        yourBtn.setClickable(false);
     }
 }, 24*60*60*1000);
```